# How can i fill my List<List<int>> from a text file using C#?

Tags: c#, list, int

I have a list of int called ...

```
List<List<int>> TotalDeEspecies = new List<List<int>>();
```

Inside that list I have stored the number of Animals that I have in my simulator and the number of cycles of a given process

If I save all the values in a text file,

```
 using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"../../Archive/TextFileTotalEspecies.txt"))
        {
            foreach (List<int> list in TotalDeEspecies)
            {
                foreach (int s in list)
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(s);
                }
                sr.WriteLine("End Animal");
            }
            sr.Close();
            File.AppendAllText(@"../../Archivos/TextFileTotalEspecies.txt", "End" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

I have this.

```
14
21
80
122
172
End Animal
304
277
265
314
394
End Animal
244
192
137
90
79
End Animal
398
470
478
434
315
End Animal
End
```

I use "End Animal" and "End" to identify the end of the animal and the end of file.

now my question is, How can i fill again my...

```
List<List<int>> TotalDeEspecies = new List<List<int>>();
```

using the Text File generated above?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @user, you have successfully utilized `StreamWriter`.  Have you investigated `StreamReader`?

Comment: [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a good way to read it (easier to work with than `StreamReader`, considering you don't need too much control or complexity).

Comment: Also, why did you close the file and then append "End"? Just add a `sr.WriteLine("End");` at the end. Then you don't need to manually close the `StreamWriter`, the `using` takes care of that.

Comment: Please comment if you must use this format or you just decided for some reason that custom format is better than existing ones (like JSON/XML) because it is harder to read and hence more interesting to write code for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code snippet...

```
List<List<int>> values = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> innerValues = new List<int>();
foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(@"../../Archivos/TextFileTotalEspecies.txt"))
{
    if (item == "End Animal")
    {
        values.Add(innerValues);
        innerValues = new List<int>();
        continue;
    }
    else if (item == "End")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        innerValues.Add(int.Parse(item));
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

does it need to be that file format? if not consider this:

each animal is a List

collapse each animal with:

```
String.Join("~", animal.ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

then write each animal to a new line.

then each line can be converted back into a List with:

```
List<int> animal = new List<int>(stringLine.Split('~').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray());
```

Wouldn't that be a simpler solution than the file format you currently have?

your output code then becomes:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"../../Archive/TextFileTotalEspecies.txt"))
    {
        foreach (List<int> list in TotalDeEspecies)
        {
            string s = String.Join("~", list.ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
            sr.WriteLine(s);
        }
        sr.Close();
        File.AppendAllText(@"../../Archivos/TextFileTotalEspecies.txt", "End" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

you get it back with StreamReader:

```
    string stringLine = sr.ReadLine();
    values.Add(new List<int>(stringLine.Split('~').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray()));
```